# Gettign Unterminated string at character exception in JSONArray

Tags: arrays

I have a String [{'type':'01661140020359^@'}]. While initializing jsonarray with this string, am getting  Unterminated string at character due to ^@. how to skip or avoid such characters?

Comment: Where is the string generated with that character? It's almost always best to fix at the source than writing code to ignore the symptoms.

Comment: Your string is a valid JSON. Can you show us your code?

Comment: @Stasel I suspect the `^@` is a `\0`, which is not allowed in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

the character like ^@ in the string ,will not effect jsonarray initialization

it may other issue

try this  [{"type":"01661140020359^@"}